# Is 12mm too much of a transition on flooring?

Tags: vinyl-flooring, transition

Debating tearing up tile that is 1/4” high or just leaving and putting vinyl floor over it. Is a 12mm transition down to the hardwood floor too much? What would I use for transition strip that would be best?

Comment: I don't think it would be too much, but then again I am not going to be using it.  It would bug some people, so you should try something for a few days to see if it is okay for you.

Comment: Is this in a doorway or over a wide expanse?

Comment: This is entirely a matter of opinion (making it off topic here). I've seen many that high, but I'd avoid it when practical. I can give no other answer.

Comment: I'm a bit confused: 1/4" = ~6mm. Where does the 12mm (~1/2") gap come from?

Comment: Is the existing tile going to be a good substrate for your vinyl? Sheet vinyl will show every imperfection in the subfloor, and tile will have plenty of them (grout lines, etc.).

Comment: 1/4" of tile, plus 1/8" of vinyl, plus 1/8" of transition flange, roughly equals 1/2" (12mm). It's a reasonable estimate.

Comment: you might remove the first row or two of tiles and use cement to build a gentle-enough "ramp" that the vinyl doesn't mind it.

Answer (score 1):

That's not a very large offset. There are many types of transition strips available at you home or flooring store. You'll need to do a little checking out and find the one that works best for you.  An example of one type is shown below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It depends a lot on where it is. In the middle of somewhere, or in a doorway, vinyl will wear at the high point. In a doorway, a taper strip from one room to the other - perhaps 6" across - would be a better transition, like a sort of furring strip across the threshold.